# After updating ubuntu 14.04 to 15.10 desktop not appearing only command prompt shows

Tags: boot

Dpkg: error processing package libkf5prison1:amd64 (--configure)
dependency problem - leavino apport report written because Maxreports is reached alreasy

Unable to copy paste as window not appearing nor terminal when power on laptop only command prompt appears.

Comment: More details and be specific

Answer (score 0):

Do Ctrl+Alt+F7 to get into XWindows Terminal.
This does happened to me for an old desktop. I installed Ubuntu once again and it got fixed as I tried various stuff but nothing worked out.

Comment: It should be Ctrl+Alt+F1 to F6.

Comment: Not working its a problem releted to karnel